Can a boost converter output different voltage levels according to the reference voltage?
Is it possible to design a boost converter such that the boost converter outputs different voltage levels according to a reference value?

that's how they usually work where you attenuate the output to match Vref

Yes. You will have to ask a more detailed question to get anything useful to you.

Besides tracking converters, a few ICs exist with an external reference voltage pin, for example the LT3473.  Since you can provide the reference voltage you can indeed have the output vary proportionally to another voltage.

From my observation, the Vref is usually one or multiple fixed values. But is there really a need for switching between high and low voltage on the fly? For example, the reference at this moment is 15V, and at next moment the reference is set to 12V, some how like this.

As @D.A.S. mentioned, most adjustable converters use an external voltage divider that presents a scaled-down version of the output to a feedback pin and adjust the output to keep the voltage at the feedback pin at a constant level relative to an internal fixed reference voltage, given in the datasheet (1.2V and 2.5V are typical values). By changing the values of the resistors of the voltage divider, the output voltage can be changed.
But it sounds like you are asking if there is a device that functions as a boost converter whose output voltage "copies" another desired voltage; that functionality is called "tracking". While I am not personally aware of any boost converters that have that built into them (most of the devices that do exist are linear regulators), there is a good conceptual discussion of how to build some external circuitry to trick a converter that is expecting to be tracking its own output into copying a different voltage here: Boost Converter with Vin tracking
